# In Google Sheets, is there a way to check if a cell or a column of cells is use in a calculation elsewhere in the sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to know if there a way to check if a cell or a column of cells is use in a calculation elsewhere in the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pasting `=na()` in the cells you want to track, then choose for **Edit > Search and replace > Find >** `#N/A` to locate cells that depend on the cells you filled. Finally, choose **Edit > Undo** to restore the original values.